# Gradle dependencies of local dependency

Tags: java, gradle, build, dependencies, build.gradle

So let's say I have project A, which requires certain dependencies. And I have project B, which has project A as one of its dependencies. So I have the following code in project B's build.gradle:

project B's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile files("projectA_dir/build/libs/projectA.jar")
}
```

However, since Gradle does not include project A's dependencies in projectA.jar by default. I was wondering if there's a way to let project B successfully compile project A without creating a fatjar for project A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **jar** file **doesn't contain the [transitive](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) dependencies** and doesn't have a pom file which describes the dependencies used by the module.

It means that, if you are importing a jar file using  `compile files` **you have to specify the dependencies also in your project**.

You should use a **maven repository**, private or public, to avoid the issue.
In this case, gradle downloads the dependencies using the pom file which will contains the dependencies list.

Comment: I just inserted  `apply plugin: 'maven'`, run `gradlew install` for Project A and insert dependency information of project A in the build.gradle file of project B. It worked like magic. Thank you so much.